# Missing _layout folder in Jekyll to add Disqus Comments

Tags: comments, jekyll, disqus

I want to add Disqus to my blog. I am using Jekyll version 3 which uses Gem based themes. To add disqus comments I need to add disqus Universal code in `_layout` folder which does not exist. Any advice on where to add disqus code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disqus is available via the default theme-gem **`minima`** for Jekyll 3.3.x and above.
From the theme's [documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/minima#enabling-comments-via-disqus):

> #### Enabling comments (via Disqus)
>
> Optionally, if you have a Disqus account, you can tell Jekyll to use
>   it to show a comments section below each post.
>
> To enable it, add the following lines to your Jekyll site config:
>
> ```
> disqus:
>   shortname: my_disqus_shortname
> ```
>
> Comments are enabled by default and will only appear in production, i.e., **`JEKYLL_ENV=production`**